Mysterious date conversion
I received a SQL backup and am trying to convert some dates to a MM-DD-YYYY date format. The problem is for the life of me I can't figure out what the original date format is.
The date format is 5 digits. I know that the following date 80329 is 12/03/2020
From early research I thought this might be an msdate, but this format would convert to somewhere in the 2100s.

This seems to be clarion date format. Which RDBMS do you use? Here an example for a SQL Server DB: https://dbfiddle.uk/W8D5Hz8A

Does this answer your question? How to format an integer date (5 digits) to yyyy-mm-dd in SQL Server?

Question should include more details on the source of this "SQL backup"

"trying to convert some dates to a MM-DD-YYYY date format" is not possible, a date does not have a format, it only can be formatted.

I think a few more examples would be useful even if you don't know what dates they translate to.

The straight conversion of the Clarion date value:
SELECT 
    ClarionDate, 
    DATEADD(DAY, ClarionDate, '1800-12-28') AS TrueDate
FROM 
    Table1;

Source:
Understanding the Clarion Date Format: A Comprehensive Guide
